# Regex pattern to see if a string contains a number in a range

Tags: ruby, string

I'm trying to match a number between 400 and 499 anywhere in a string. For example, both:

```
string = "[401] One too three"
string2 = "Yes 450 sir okay"
```

should match. Both:

```
string3 = "[123] Test"
string4 = "This is another string"
```

should fail.

What's the best way to write the regex? I wrote:

```
string =~ /\d{3}/
```

to see if the string contains a three digit integer. How can I see if that's within the range?

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot the range. Question updated.

Comment: They're separate strings, yes, and the format is irrelevant.

Comment: I would just extract the number-string using regex then use something like `include?` or `cover?`.

Comment: I suggest "One to three" or "One two three" :-)

Comment: I was originally going to go with One 2 Three but my r&b group isn't ready for the spotlight

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't actually need the number afterwords, and just need to determine **yes** or **no** the string contains a number in the range of 400-499, you can:

1. Check that you are at the beginning of a line, or have a non-digit character followed by
2. the digit '4' followed by
3. Any 2 digits followed by
4. the end of a line or a non-digit character

so you end up with a regex looking something like

```
regex = /(?:^|\D)4\d{2}(?:\D|$)/
```

or, by using negative look ahead/look behinds:

```
regex = /(?<!\d)4\d{2}(?!\d)/
```

and you need step 1 and 4 above to make rule out numbers such as 1400-1499 and 4000-4999 (and other such numbers with more than 3 digits that have 400-499 somewhere buried in them). You can then make use of [`String#match?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-match-3F) in newer ruby versions to get just a simple boolean:

```
string.match?(regex)   # => true
string2.match?(regex)  # => true
string3.match?(regex)  # => false
string4.match?(regex)  # => false
"1400".match?(regex)   # => false
"400".match?(regex)    # => true
"4000".match?(regex)   # => false
"[1400]".match?(regex) # => false
"[400]".match?(regex)  # => true
"[4000]".match?(regex) # => false
```

Fairly simple regex, no need to pull out the match and convert it to an integer if you just need a simple **yes** or **no**

Answer (score 6):

```
def doit(str, rng)
  str.gsub(/-?\d+/).find { |s| rng.cover?(s.to_i) }
end

doit "[401] One too three", 400..499     #=> "401"
doit "Yes 450 sir okay", 400..499        #=> "450"
doit "Yes -450 sir okay", -499..400      #=> "-450"
doit "[123] Test", 400..499              #=> nil
doit "This is another string", 400..499  #=> nil
```

Recall that [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) returns an enumerator, when used with a single argument and no block. The enumerator merely generates matches and performs no substitutions. I've found a number of situations, as here, where this form of the method can be used to advantage.

if `str` may contain the representations of multiple integers within the specified range, and all such are desired, simply replace [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) with [Enumerable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select):

```
"401, 532 and -126".gsub(/-?\d+/).select { |s| (-127..451).cover?(s.to_i) }
  #=> ["401", "-126"]
```

Comment: This is indeed smart!

Comment: @mudasobwa, I think this would be used a lot more if there were a separate `String` method that took a pattern as its argument and returned an enumerator, perhaps `each_match`. Were there such a method there would be no need for the form of `gsub` that returns an enumerator.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using a general regex to first extract the number from each line.  Then, use a regular script to check the range:

```
s = "[404] Yes sir okay"
data = s.match(/\[(\d+)\]/)
data.captures
num = data[1].to_i

if (num >= 400 && num < 500)
    print "Match"
else
    print "No Match"
end
```

### Demo

The pattern I wrote should actually work to match any number in brackets, anywhere in the string.

Comment: I think it should be `[0]` but I had no idea bout the `.captures` method — _thank-you_.

Comment: No, the zeroeth capture group is the entire pattern.  But, you only want the number, which is in the first capture group.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the digits with a regex, convert the capture group to integer and ask Ruby if they're between your bounds:

```
s = "[499] One too three"
lo = 400
hi = 499

puts s =~ /(\d{3})/ && $1.to_i.between?(lo, hi)
```

Comment: Careful...this would match any three digits, not just three digits contained within brackets.

Comment: OP specified in a comment "format is irrelevant", so I'm assuming the literal brackets should be rejected in the regex. It's pretty easy to add them if the OP so desires.

Comment: Yeah, `$1` is the first match. There are [all kinds of dollar sign variables in Ruby](https://gist.github.com/dvliman/10402435). Matz borrowed it from Perl.